# LEFT JOIN SUBSTITUTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, left-join, transpose

I have a table TOPIC (Article_ID,ROOT_TOPIC_ID,LEVEL,TOPIC_NAME).
The Select Result are as following:

[image]

I need to transpose the resultset, but I'm using multiple left join for each level.

The resultset that I want is something like this:

[image]

Multiple left self joins are deprecating the performance and pivoting on string column is not possible (not sure)!!

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Hi. What have you got so far? How did the zillions of similar questions/answers not help you? What does "using" mean? What does "something like" mean? We can't read our mind. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please use text when you can, like instead of these images & links. Format tables as code.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing about a left join that would prevent you from pivoting the results. If performance is poor it could be that the columns that are keys to the join are not properly or suitably indexed. Does SQLServer Management Studio advise you of any missing indexes?

```
SELECT
  Article_ID, Root_Topic_ID, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]
FROM
  (your select query here) src
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Topic_name)
  FOR LEVEL IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) pvt
```

There's nothing about the pivot that affects the performance of the original query; indeed by definition the original query has to run before it can be pivoted. Pivot is just an alternative format syntax of the GROUP/MAX(CASE WHEN) you've been given in the other answer

Answer (score 3):

Use `CASE` and condition aggregation

```
SELECT ArticleID, ROOT_TOPIC_ID, 
   MAX (CASE WHEN level = 0 THEN Topic_name END) as Level0,
   MAX (CASE WHEN level = 1 THEN Topic_name END) as Level1,
   MAX (CASE WHEN level = 2 THEN Topic_name END) as Level2,
   MAX (CASE WHEN level = 3 THEN Topic_name END) as Level3,
   MAX (CASE WHEN level = 4 THEN Topic_name END) as Level4,
   MAX (CASE WHEN level = 5 THEN Topic_name END) as Level5,
   MAX (CASE WHEN level = 6 THEN Topic_name END) as Level6
FROM Topic
GROUP BY ArticleID, ROOT_TOPIC_ID
```

Using subqueries is possible as well, however, in this case the performance of conditional aggregation will be probably better.

```
SELECT ArticleID, ROOT_TOPIC_ID, 
   (
       SELECT top 1 Topic_name FROM Topic t WHERE t.ArticleID = Topic.ArticleID AND t.ROOT_TOPIC_ID = Topic.ROOT_TOPIC_ID AND level = 0
   ) as Level0,
   (
       SELECT top 1 Topic_name FROM Topic t WHERE t.ArticleID = Topic.ArticleID AND t.ROOT_TOPIC_ID = Topic.ROOT_TOPIC_ID AND level = 1
   ) as Level1,
   -- an so on
FROM Topic
GROUP BY ArticleID, ROOT_TOPIC_ID
```